# Define Field as an Unsigned Integer With Web2py/Pydal

Tags: python, mysql, web2py, pydal

**Is it possible to define a web2py model with an unsigned integer `Field`? If so, how may it be done?**

The underlying database is MySQL and the equivalent `CREATE TABLE` statement is below.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
;
```

I have made three attempts to do this, unsuccessfully. The following snippets are the attempts.

```py
db.define_table('t', Field('value', 'integer unsigned'))
```

```py
db.define_table('t', Field('value', 'integer', options=['unsigned']))
```

```py
db.define_table('t', Field('value', 'integer', options=['UNSIGNED']))
```

I have found no mention of unsigned integers in either the [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Field-constructor) or [pydal](https://pydal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#pydal.objects.Field) documentation. Of course it's possible that unsigned integers just aren't supported by either web2py or pydal. I am using web2py version 2.20.4-stable+timestamp.2020.05.02.22.03.36, pydal version 20200502.2, and MySQL version 5.7.25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to define a custom_qualifier on the field:

```
Field('value', 'integer', custom_qualifier='UNSIGNED')
```

It just gets appended to the field definition when migrating

This'll make the project less portable, since unsigned ints aren't a thing in PostgreSQL or MSSQL, for example.

Comment: Works well. Fortunately, portability is of no concern for this particular project.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe pydal explicitly supports the unsigned integer type, but everything should work if you simply specify `type='integer'`, as long as you are not using pydal to do migrations (i.e., it will not *create* a new unsigned integer column for you, but it will work with existing columns).

Comment: Thank you. I used your solution 18 months ago and can confirm that pydal won't change an INTEGER UNSIGNED column to INTEGER. Unfortunately, another dev was migrating this app recently and the column ended up either being created or modified as an INTEGER.